# Multiple Refactored Sliders in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

First time coding anything, so thank you for the help!

I'm writing a very slider-heavy app, where there's often multiple sliders and their outputs in the same card. Since I'm reusing the same slider format/theming over and over again, I refactored the slider into its own widget with a few often-adjusted parameters. This also allowed me to add some plus/minus buttons on either side for smaller, incremental changes to go along with the slider every time.

My problem is that in a card with multiple sliders, I don't know how to separate their values. So currently all the slider's outputs (and positions on the slider bar) are linked. Here's an example pic:

[Test Card w/ Red, Green, and Blue Sliders and Outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUfz9.png)

And here's a simplified version of the code with only the relevant bits:

Customized Slider Widget (code updated 6/30):

```
typedef SliderCallback(double);

class CustomSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomSlider({
    @required this.onChanged,
    @required this.onIncrement,
    @required this.onDecrement,
    @required this.sliderTitle,
    @required this.sliderMin,
    @required this.sliderMax,
  });

  final SliderCallback onChanged;
  final SliderCallback onIncrement;
  final SliderCallback onDecrement;
  final String sliderTitle;
  final double sliderMin;
  final double sliderMax;

  @override
  _CustomSliderState createState() => _CustomSliderState();
}

class _CustomSliderState extends State<CustomSlider> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
       leftArrowButton(),
        Slider(
            value: sliderValue.toDouble(),
            min: widget.sliderMin,
            max: widget.sliderMax,
            onChanged: (double newValue) {
              setState(
                () {
                  sliderValue = newValue.round();
                },
              );
              widget.onChanged(sliderValue);
            },
          ),
        rightArrowButton(),
      ],
    );
  }

  IconButton leftArrowButton() {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back_ios
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        if (sliderValue != widget.sliderMin) {
          setState(
            () {
              sliderValue--;
            },
          );
          widget.onDecrement(sliderValue);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  IconButton rightArrowButton() {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_forward_ios
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        if (sliderValue != widget.sliderMax) {
          setState(
            () {
              sliderValue++;
            },
          );
          widget.onIncrement(sliderValue);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Setup and Build Method of the page where the Sliders are called (code added 6/30):

```
class _ColorCardState extends State<ColorCard> {
int _sliderValue = 0; //Don't think is needed anymore...
int _redValue = 0;
int _greenValue = 0;
int _blueValue = 0;
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
```

Called Slider Widget (code updated 6/30):

```
CustomSlider(
            sliderTitle: 'RED',
            sliderMin: 0,
            sliderMax: 255,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _redValue = value;
              });
            }, //The slider itself
            onDecrement: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _redValue = value;
              });
            }, //The Minus button
            onIncrement: (value) {
              setState(() {
               _redValue = value;
              });
            }, //The Plus button
          ),
```

Elsewhere in the Widget tree, each slider/button combo has a corresponding String output (code updated 6/30):

```
Text(_redValue.toString()),
```

I understand that the issue is that all the sliders output to the same "sliderValue", and that I need to separate them into separate named values. Ideally those values would name themselves, using the sliderTitle parameter, eg, REDsliderValue, or something like that. But I'm struggling to figure out how to do that given the refactored nature of the widget.

Thank you so much for any advice you can give! And I'm assuming there's some errors/sloppiness in the code... first timer over here!

Comment: `class _CustomSliderState extends State<CustomSlide>` should be `class _CustomSliderState extends State<CustomSlider>` , it has a type in `CustomSlider`.
When you create multiple instances of `CustomSlider( )` widget, the `instance variables`  will be separate for each instance.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo! That is good to know that each widget has its own unique set of variables. So how do I call those unique variables later on? How do I specify which slider's variable to display?

Comment: One way i can quickly think of is to have 3 variables which represent the values for 3 sliders, `sliderRedValue` `sliderGreenValue` `sliderBlueValue`. These variables will be declared at the top(class level) in the `Widget` where you create the 3 `CustomSliders`. Inside of each of the `setState()`, update the corresponding variable; for example updated `sliderRedValue` inside `setState()` of `CustomSlider` representing the `Red` slider. Also do read about State Management in flutter and different approaches.

Comment: That works like a charm! Thank you, this is a big step forward for me... I've been avoiding learning about State Management so far, as I wanted to get the hang of UI elements first, but you're right, I think it's time. One more issue Im having: since each slider instance links back to the same code, they're still all linked. If I change the thumb position on one, all the others move in unison, even though the R/G/B variables themselves are split up. I assume this is due to the setState within the Widget updating  "sliderValue" when slid, which marks it as dirty on all instances of the widget?

Comment: Oh. Each instance should be independent now, can you update with the latest code?

Comment: Definitely. Just updated. Also added the build Method code, where the variables are initiated. Really all I've done is change each individual slider's setState to update _redValue/_greenValue/blueValue as needed.

Comment: I tried to create a minimal reproducible code [here](https://pastebin.com/vpbyNKxV). Sliders work independently. Try re-running your app.

Comment: Did it work for you? i didn't change other than addition of a missing `)`

Comment: Took me a while to figure it out... I had an errant import of an unrelated .dart file, which was messing with the "sliderValue". Once I squashed that bug, it was fixed it... mostly. One more issue (pushing my luck here, haha). In my real world use-case, the card actually has multiple tabs to select (various way of mixing colors), each with at least two sliders. The sliders and output displayed are determined by a conditional statement checking a "selectedOption" variable. Here's what happens: https://vimeo.com/434911144 Here's the full (ugh... I'm sorry) code: https://pastebin.com/cwWC6zKY

Comment: And here's the refactored Slider widget code, in full: https://pastebin.com/zG8R8m5N

Comment: I might be not able to give sufficient time to go through the entire code but saw your output video, problem seems to be caused by some slider variables being accidentally shared in the different tabs.

Comment: Totally understood - you’ve helped me out so much already! Maybe it’s not super clear from the video, but the sliders are linked based on their positions in each tab. The first slider in each tab is linked, the second in each tab, etc. Which leads me to believe it’s some weird confluence between the way Flutter paints things on screen and the fact that the tabs are displayed/hidden (created/destroyed?) by means of an if/else statement, rather then something more elegant. I have a few (janky) work arounds in mind that I might try out...